# finding the difference between elements of a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a random vector in matlab of length 200 x1

```
x= rand(200,1)
```

I want to write a line of code that finds the difference between every 3 elements of x, that is
x(4)-x(1) and then x(5)-x(2) and then x(6)-x(3).

```
for i=1:length(x)-3
diff= x(i+3)- x(i)
end
```

Would this work? thank you

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to write `diff(i)=...` to prevent a scalar `diff` from being overwritten on every iteration. Or, better yet, you can avoid the loop altogether with the one-liner `diff=x(4:end)-x(1:end-3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `diff` as a variable name, since it is an [in built function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) which you are shadowing.

You are close, but you are repeatedly overwriting the output, you need to store it in an array during your loop

```
delta = NaN(size(x)); % preallocate the output for better memory management
for ii = 1:length(x)-3
    delta(ii) = x(ii+3) - x(ii) % assign to output array
end
```

You can do this more concisely in MATLAB using array operations, specifically

```
delta = x(4:end) - x(1:end-3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is via [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution):

```
x = [4 7 8 9 6 8];
N = 3; % difference stride
y = conv(x, [1 zeros(1,N-1) -1], 'valid');
```

Example:

```
x =
     4     7     8     9     6     8
y =
     5    -1     0
```